# Aligning image nav items into 2 lines in mobile size screen in Rails app

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have nav bar in my Rails web app. I'm trying to make it responsible in mobile screen but I cannot achieve what I want. Below is image what it normally looks like in desktop screen.

[image]

When I view this in iphone5 and iphone6 size, it looks like below. Logo image is on the left and nav items are on the right.
[image]

I want to make everything centered and stretch nav items equally using full width like below:
[image]

Below is the html code I have:

```
<header class="page-header--transparent">
  <div>
        <a href="/" class="page-header-logo">
            <%= image_tag("logo-green.svg") %>
        </a>
    </div>
        <nav class="page-header-nav">
            <%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path, :class => "page-header--transparent-nav-item" %>
            <%= link_to 'Get Started', new_user_registration_path, :class => "page-header--transparent-nav-item" %>
            <%= link_to 'Contact', '/contact', :class => "page-header--transparent-nav-item" %>
        </nav>
</header>
```

Below is CSS code:

```
.page-header--transparent {
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
    padding: 12px 20px;
}

.page-header-nav {
  float: right;
}

.page-header--transparent-nav-item {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #757575;
    padding: 8px 17px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    transition: all ease-in-out 1s;
}

.page-header-logo {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 12px;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .page-header--transparent-nav-item {
        padding: 15px 10px;
    }

    .page-header--transparent {
        background-color: #ffffff;
        box-shadow: none;
        padding: 12px 20px;
    }
}
```

It would be great if anyone can give me advice!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.c {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}
.menu .m {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .c {
    display: block;
  }
  .logo {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="c">
  <div class="logo">logo</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="m">menu1</div>
    <div class="m">menu2</div>
    <div class="m">menu3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

updated using flex

Comment: When this is on full desktop screen, menus are not floating together on the right side but all dispersed.

Comment: i liked the previous answer better since using flex doesn't let me put nav items together on the right. Thank you very much for no matter what!

Comment: flex is much more powerful, since u need to get along with it ^_^

Comment: Then, do you have any advice on aggregating those nav items while using flex? I couldn't figure that part out